# How to apply rows style depending on cell data with jqgrid?

Tags: css, jqgrid

My use case is the following:

Having a table like:

```
+------------------------------+
| NOTICE  | This is notice #1  |
| WARNING | This is warning #1 |
| NOTICE  | This is notice #2  |
| ERROR   | This is error  #1  |
+------------------------------+
```

I'd like to have a specific background color for the whole rows depending of the value of first column.

To implement this, I'd like to make use of a class applied on the row so that I can skin it easily with:

```
tr.NOTICE td {background-color: Yellow}
tr.WARNING td {background-color: Orange}
tr.ERROR td {background-color: OrangeRed}
```

Not sure it is possible with jqGrid, maybe with a Custom Formatter? No idea how

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a way to do it:

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
    ...
    gridComplete: function() {
    var _rows = $(".jqgrow");
    for (var i = 0; i < _rows.length; i++) {
      _rows[i].attributes["class"].value += " " + _rows[i].childNodes[0].textContent;
    }
});0
```

Comment: Both answers looks relevant, which one would be recommended?

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
afterInsertRow:function(rowid, rowdata, rowelem){
  var status = rowdata['status']; 
  if(status=='0'){
   $("tr.jqgrow#"+rowid).addClass("ui-state-error"); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Both answers looks relevant, which one would be recommended?